# Can we update values in a table by using if condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, join, sql-update

I have 4 tables.

[image]

The identifiers are different. Hence, in Table 4 we have data to connect both the tables. But there is no relation between Table1 to any of these other 3 Tables.

I have to verify whether Table 2 and Table 3 counts match. On having the result of comparison, I need to udpate Table 1 with Pass/Fail

For eg: count of Table 2 equals to Table 3.

Comment: You'd better post what you've tried and what your expected result.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Click for Image of tables. Here there are 4 tables. I want to verify whether Table 2 and Table 3 counts match. For eg: count of Table 2 equals to Table 3. However, the identifiers are different. Hence, in Table 4 we have data to connect both the tables. On having the result of comparison. I want to udpate Table 1 with Pass/Fail

Comment: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayOdl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Joins` Or `IF EXISTS`

```
UPDATE T1 SET checklist = 'SOMETHING'
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.FIELDVALUE = T2.FIELDVALUE 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T1.FIELDVALUE = T3.FIELDVALUE
```

OR

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET checklist = 'SOMETHING'
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.FIELDVALUE  = TABLE2.FIELDVALUE)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE1.FIELDVALUE  = TABLE3.FIELDVALUE)
```

**UPDATE:** From comments

[image]

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM TABLE4 T4
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T4.Identifier = T2.Identifier 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T4.Identifier_ = T3.Identifier2
AND T2.COUNT <> T3.COUNT
)
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE1 SET RESULTS = 'Fail'
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
UPDATE TABLE1 SET RESULTS = 'Pass'
END
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. However, 2nd and 3rd table has values in common to compare and Table 1 is totally not related for these 2 tables. But, the comparison results should be updated in Table1.

Comment: This will remains unclear until you provide your tables structure, Sample data and expected output. Please edit your question   @KrishnaTeja

Comment: [Click for Image of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayOdl.png). Here there are 4 tables. I want to verify whether Table 2 and Table 3 counts match. For eg: count of Table 2 equals to Table 3. However, the identifiers are different. Hence, in Table 4 we have data to connect both the tables. On having the result of comparison. I want to udpate Table 1 with Pass/Fail and respective comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
update one
set one.assid = two.assid
from tableone_name one
inner join table_2 two on
    one.id = two .udid
inner join table_2 th on
    one.id_1 = th .id_3
```

Hope that will work